# Android: IntentFilters for components

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, cmp

What is a reasonable way to filter out specific cmp Strings with an Android IntentFilters which are declared in code in broadcast Receivers (rather than in android.xml)?

The case I'm searching for has:

```
   action = android.intent.action.MAIN
   category = android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the intent filter only works over the application in which it occurs.  This meant MAIN and LAUNCHER wasn't finding anything except for application relaunch events which weren't actually occurring.   The system freeze up was caused by a separate error on the phone, not by the FILTER actually processing over too much information.

Still not sure how to search within an app by cmp or Component but the bigger issue was not finding stuff outside the application and that has alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I do a positive test for stuff I'm interested in and ignore everything that doesn't conform, as opposed to negatively trying to throw away all possible non-interesting things and keeping what's left.  But maybe I've misunderstood your problem.

Comment: My problem is the most specific information I have is cmp data, and I don't see a way to use that in an IntentFilter in code.